# Getting Root & Leaf Nodes for a Given Id - How to?

Tags: sql, database, mysql

Assume I have a table that has the following structure:

```
=================
| Id | ParentId |
=================
| 1  | 0        |
| 2  | 1        |
| 3  | 1        |
| 4  | 2        |
| 5  | 2        |
| 6  | 3        |
| 7  | 3        |
-----------------
```

This results in a tree like this:

```
     1
    / \
  2     3
 / \   / \
4   5 6   7
```

Given an id, how do I get all the leaf nodes? So, if the given id is 2, the return should be 4 & 5. The given id will never be a leaf node itself.

I'm not sure how to modify the SQL here: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

```
SELECT t1.name FROM
category AS t1 LEFT JOIN category as t2
ON t1.category_id = t2.parent
WHERE t2.category_id IS NULL;
```

EDIT1: **Also, how do I get the root id for a given id?** So, if the given id is 2, the return should be 1.

Comment: What will the result be if the given id is 1 in your example?

Comment: I truly would recommend that you actually use the table structure as depicted in the article you pointed out. You will save yourself a lot of frustration in the long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Also, how do I get the root id for a given id? So, if the given id is 2, the return should be 1."

That's pretty easy, that's the ParentId!

You'll get the children with the following query:

```
SELECT child.Id FROM theTable current LEFT JOIN theTable child ON child.ParentId = current.Id;
```

Btw, I wouldn't recommend using `0` when the row has no parent, I'd rather use `NULL` in that case.

Comment: How can I retrieve all sub children? not only the inmediate ones?

Comment: That can't be done in a single query. You could get all the sub children by looping recursively, so just get all the children of all the children.